# Django: relation "django_site" does not exist in app with psql using sites framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-sites

after switching from sqlite to postgres for local dev db, I am unable to run migrations for my app.

Several fixes and approaches I've attempted have not resolved (ex: [Django: relation "django_site" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925726/django-relation-django-site-does-not-exist)).

python: 3.6.3

Django Version: 1.11.9

psql (PostgreSQL): 10.1

installed apps:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
# Default Django apps:
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.gis',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'django.contrib.admin',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
'widget_tweaks',
'mptt',
'channels',
'honeypot',
'gunicorn',
'djangosecure',

# Allauth
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
'users.apps.UsersConfig', #because of a signal
'common',
'geo',
'community',
'objects',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

in .env file:

```
SITE_ID=1
```

solutions I have attempted:

Cleared all migrations and migration files and ran:

`$ ./manage.py makemigrations`

then I have attempted sequential and manual migrations of apps starting with django.contrib, such as:

`$ ./manage.py migrate sites` (first)

then applying additional migrations. but regardless of how I order app migrations does not change err or allow migration to complete.

I have also tried migrations with `--fake-initial`.

it looks like it is calling a site object before creating site model.

project/utils/middleware.py:

```
class SiteMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)

        request.current_site = current_site

        if current_site.domain in settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
            request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[str(current_site)]
```

.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:

```
class CursorWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, cursor, db):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.db = db

    WRAP_ERROR_ATTRS = frozenset(['fetchone', 'fetchmany', 'fetchall', 'nextset'])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        cursor_attr = getattr(self.cursor, attr)
        if attr in CursorWrapper.WRAP_ERROR_ATTRS:
            return self.db.wrap_database_errors(cursor_attr)
        else:
            return cursor_attr

    def __iter__(self):
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            for item in self.cursor:
                yield item

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            self.close()
        except self.db.Database.Error:
            pass

    def callproc(self, procname, params=None):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.callproc(procname)
            else:
                return self.cursor.callproc(procname, params)

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    def executemany(self, sql, param_list):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
```

migration traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 227, in handle
    self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/management.py", line 20, in create_default_site
    if not Site.objects.using(using).exists():
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 670, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 517, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 858, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
```

./manage.py showmigrations sites:

```
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
```

admin traceback:

```
File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                         ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
244.             response = middleware_method(request)

File "/Users/.../project/utils/middleware.py" in process_request
47.             current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
374.         num = len(clone)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
232.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
899.             raise original_exception

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
889.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin
Exception Value: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                         ^
```

thanks

Comment: Don't abbreviate the traceback like that. We need to know why a middleware is being called as part of the migration process, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: In addition to the traceback, please post the class or function containing the line causing the error.

Comment: You've shown the full traceback for going to `/admin` but you haven't shown the full traceback from when you try to migrate.

Comment: migration tracebook is included

Comment: What does `manage.py showmigrations sites` display?

Comment: sites
     [X] 0001_initial
     [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You say that `manage.py showmigrations sites` shows the following:

```
sites
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
```

That means that Django thinks it has already carried out the migrations for the `sites` app (perhaps this is because you used `--fake-initial`)

You could use `--fake` to mark the sites migrations as unapplied, then rerun migrate:

```
manage.py migrate sites zero --fake
manage.py migrate sites
```

Comment: thanks Alasdair, good thinking. was able to complete migrations using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to login to admin and can see group **Sites** there then please try modifying and saving the site object.

Try organizing the entries in **Installed App**s as follows :

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

let me know if this work.

Comment: cannot access/log into admin due to this issue. organizing apps does not change output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, some how the Site model does not exist during migration, all I did is wrap the whole thing in a try catch and the exception does not seem to happened again after the initial Site migration.

```
class SiteMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            try:
                current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
            except Site.DoesNotExist:
                current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)

            request.current_site = current_site

            if current_site.domain in settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
                request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[str(current_site)]
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Error: %s' % ex)
```